# Iterate through complicated json object and array

Tags: jquery, json

This is my json structure
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=fb2a15d2df238449142d98ad015961f9

I'm trying to loop trough results like this:

```
        success: function(data) {
            for(var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++)
            {
                var product = data.result[i];
               alert(product);
            }
        }
```

Then in this 'result' object I've got another Object in Object and Array, how can I get this value?

[image]

Comment: `alert(product.image.large.url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results = data.tw_objects.tw_object.results.result;
for (i=0; i<results.length; i++){
   console.log(results[i].image.large.url)
}`

Comment: this is considering that data has the json that you have shared in jsoneditoronline